# KDE Plasma Wayland cursor is malfunctioning

Tags: kali-linux, display, cursor

This is a fresh install of Kali Linux in a virtual machine following a package update & upgrade. I selected Wayland KDE plasma as my DE when I was setting it up. If this changes anything, my resolution is `2560x1440`.

A strange issue began surfacing as I was writing a script, my cursor glitches to the wrong icon (ex. a typing icon when default mouse is supposed to be there or a link select cursor when i'm typing.) I've tried rebooting, and it doesn't seem to be fixing itself. I couldn't find anyone else with the same issues/no solutions.